# Should I install zip or use gzip?

Tags: software-recommendation, compression

I have downloaded some `.zip` files. I wish to decompress them (I have `unzip`), modify them, and compress them again (into separate compressed files, one decompressed file per compressed file). I have no plan to use the files on another machine. I'm trying to figure out whether to `apt-get install zip` or to `gzip` them. (I have `gzip`.) What are the advantages of each — in general and specifically in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the main advantage of zip over gzip is that it's more widespread in the Windows community.

In your case it might be more or less equivalent.

M.

Answer (score 3):

Sticking with .zip can be a good idea for the sake of consistency. If you end up creating scripts that operate on these files, using a consistent format will keep things simpler for you. Of course, this doesn't exclude the possibility of converting the original files to gzip format and sticking with gzip.